# How do I update & commit a file in a checkout hook, and should I?

Tags: git, continuous-integration, githooks

**Some background:**
I have a beef with CI systems in that they are triggered on a pull request, but not on target branch updates.

Consider 2 pull requests with no merge conflicts, but they have logical conflicts with each other. Each passes the CI push & pr tests.

The first is merged to master. Now merging the second with master would cause a logical problem. However, there are no merge conflicts and the CI status says we are good to go because the tests were run on older code.
In short: It looks good, but is bad.

**My thoughts on a fix:**
Force a conflict.
On any branch of off master, have a git-checkout hook update a timestamp file. Now that timestamp can be merged into master if it's the next merge, but will conflict with anyone else doing work.

Now, a branch that has no conflicts and passes CI builds is guaranteed good to go.
Does that sound right?

**Requirement:**
I need a hook that updates the timestamp file and commits it locally on any branch off of master. How would I do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a script that seems to do the right thing. It hasn't been thoroughly tested.

```
#!/bin/sh

# https://git-blame.blogspot.ca/2013/06/checking-current-branch-programatically.html
if BRANCH=$(git symbolic-ref --short -q HEAD)
then
  ON_BRANCH=true
else
  ON_BRANCH=false
fi

MASTER_SHA=`git show-ref --heads -s master`
PREV_SHA=$1
CURRENT_SHA=$2
WAS_CHECKOUT=$3

if [ "$WAS_CHECKOUT" == "1" ] && [ "$MASTER_SHA" == "$CURRENT_SHA" ] && $ON_BRANCH && [ "$BRANCH" != "master" ];
then
  STAMP="$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)/.stamp"
  echo "$(date +%Y-%m-%d:%H:%M:%S) - $(git config user.name)" >| "$STAMP"
  git add "$STAMP"
  git commit -m "auto stamp update"
fi
```